# How to put DB file from application's bundle in the Library/Application support/ directory?

Tags: database, sqlite, osx-yosemite, nsfilemanager

I'm developing a OS X app with sqlite3 and I want to copy the database from the application's bundle to Library/Application support/ directory because I need read/write on the db, however, the sql is copied to my documents folder and I don't want that location. My code:

```
- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sql"];
}

- (void)openDB {
    NSString *destinationPath = [self filePath];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sql"];
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        //Error
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want, what is the question?

Comment: Is your question about 'where application data lives' or is it more about 'populating a database with initial fixtures' or something else entirely?

Comment: Assuming this was not a user file, but rather a database used by the app, you would probably store it in the _Application Support_ folder as discussed in the _The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files_ section of [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). If this was a user file, you'd prompt the user where _they_ wanted to put it. If it was a temporary file, you'd use temporary folder.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it's a database used by the app and I want to store it in the Application Support folder.

Comment: @Zaph How to copy DB file from application's bundle to the Application Support folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file like this belongs in the `Application Support` folder of the `Library`. So, instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`, use `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`. Also, as the [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) documentation says, "All content in this directory should be placed in a custom subdirectory whose name is that of your app’s bundle identifier or your company."

For example:

```
- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSString *applicationSupport = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *applicationFolder = [applicationSupport stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
    return [applicationFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sql"];
}
```

---

By the way, when creating this file, remember to create the folder:

```
- (void)openDB {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *destinationPath = [self filePath];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        NSError *error;
        if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[destinationPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:nil error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%s: createDirectoryAtPath error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        }

        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDB" ofType:@"sql"];
        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%s: copyItemAtPath error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        }
    }
}
```